# Studio Monitor's Cone not making sound after playing loud music through it

Tags: audio, audio-processing

I was playing some very loud pop music through a studio monitor (ADAM A8X), and after about 5 seconds the sound stopped coming out of the cone and only came through the speaker. After shutting it off for a few minutes and trying again, no sound was coming from the cone. I assume I broke something, but don't know where to start in terms of fixing it. Any advice?

Comment: Have you checked the fuse? It should be connected to the cone but not to the speaker.

Comment: Is that the part right below where it connects to the power socket?

Comment: If so, I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: It's in the protection stage, typically around a corner, and after the mains input.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suite for Sound Design SE (https://sound.stackexchange.com/) or Engineering SE (https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic

Answer (score 1):

If the woofer cone isn't moving but there is still sound coming from the tweeter (on top), than you have blown either the woofer or an amplifier channel.

The woofer it not that difficult to replace (I think, it's just screwed in from the front) but the replacement woofer will be expensive. I would pop out the woofer and measure the impedance of the coil with a multi-meter. If it measures "infintity" the woofer is dead. If it measures a few Ohms, it's fine.

If you are lucky you have just toasted a thermal fuse, but without a service manual that's hard to locate and replace.

Comment: Ok, the multi-meter said OL resistance. I also read [here](https://gearspace.com/board/geekzone/1325829-repairing-adam-audio-a8x.html) that a standard multimeter might not be good enough. Anyway, is my only option to buy a replacement woofer?

Comment: What you read is correct when you are interested in the impedance curve, but here this is not what you need to check (at least not for a first step troubleshooting). What Hilmar (very correctly in my opinion) suggests is that you check the continuity of the voice coil. If you have a multi-meter with continuity check (this is the "mode" that rings in short-circuits), this is what you need to check. If you hear a ringing then you should check the fuse and if the fuse is OK, then unfortunately you'll have to check the amplifier channel for destroyed transistors.

Comment: You need to have the multi meter in the lowest setting (typically 200 Ohms and it should read 7-ish Ohms or thereabouts). if you are not sure, you can use connect the terminals of a small battery of the woofer (ONLY for a SHORT moment). If the woofer makes a pop sound and it moves, than it's still alive. Make sure the woofer is disconnected from the speaker. And yes, this is better fit for the forums that @ZaellixA has suggested.